# Using OBR on Virgo 3.5

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, obr

I'm looking for a neat way to deploy and manage bundles on our Virgo container, but also want to ensure that should we want to move from Virgo in a few years, we're not heavily tied to it.  We're using Maven, so get OBR for free, which could save us some work having to maintain a list of the dependency chains.

With that in mind, after having read this article;- [How to deploy OSGi apps and dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926863/how-to-deploy-osgi-apps-and-dependencies) and some the Virgo 3.5 docs, I'm slightly at odds about the best approach.

The Virgo docs suggest using the plan mechanism, but this ties our deployment descriptors to Virgo (not what I'm after).  The article suggests I can use OBR through the GoGo console, which now ships as standard with Virgo.  However, when trying to use this console to manage OBR, all I get is

```
osgi> repos add /home/fuzzy/.m2/repository/repository.xml
No repository admin service available
```

I've done some more hunting through the Virgo docs, but can't find anything in reference to OBR - only bug reports suggesting that some of the OBR commands have been left in the GoGo shell, inappropriately.

I've also written to the Virgo forum, but no-one seems to really want to help there.  Before I go down the route of tying us to Virgo plans, I thought I'd have a quick go here.

Any help, greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, downloaded and installed org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-1.6.6.jar - however, get exactly the same error.  Asked the same question of the Virgo user group, and the answer that came back is that OBR is not supported.  Maybe I'm missing something here, but there's very little information about on this topic.  If you know better - please update this thread for the sake of others!

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear - you need a repository admin service. [Felix provides an implementation](http://felix.apache.org/site/downloads.cgi) (download *Bundle Repository*).

Comment: downloaded and installed org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-1.6.6.jar - however, get exactly the same error.

Comment: Have you checked if a repository admin service is available? I have don't know about Virgo, but in Karaf or Felix the web-console offers a list of all registered services.